# API calls break on iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift

In our app, we are making rest API calls with `URLSession.shared.data(for:,delegate:)` and JSONDecoder. On iOS>=16.1, it works. But on iOS=>17.0 using TestFlight, it crashes. It's hard investigate this bug cause I'm stuck on Xcode 14.2 on MacOS 12.6. I can confirm on the server that the API call returns a statusCode of 200. So I assume the issue it might be the JSONDecoder since I can't even catch the error and show it in my UI.
Here's some API code for context:

```
func sendRequest<T: Decodable>(endpoint: Endpoint, responseModel: T.Type, allowRetry: Bool = true, authManager: AuthManager? = nil, keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) async -> Result<T, RequestError> {
        
        var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = endpoint.scheme
        urlComponents.host = endpoint.host
        urlComponents.path = endpoint.path
        urlComponents.queryItems = endpoint.queryItems

        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return .failure(.invalidURL(nil))}
        
    
        var request = URLRequest(url: url, timeoutInterval: 5.0)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = endpoint.header
        request.httpMethod = endpoint.method.rawValue
        
        
        
        if let body = endpoint.body {
           
            do {
                request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
             } catch {
               
                return .failure(.unexpected(error.localizedDescription))
            }
        }
        
        do {
          
            
           let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request, delegate: nil)
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return .failure(.noResponse(nil))}
             switch response.statusCode {
            case 204:
                return .success("" as! T)
            case 200...299:
                 print("done")
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
                
               let result = try decoder.decode(responseModel, from: data)
                
                return .success(result)
               
            case 400:
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 let error = try decoder.decode(CheckoutError.self, from: data)
 
                 return .failure(.badRequest(error.error))
            
            }
        } catch {
             
            guard let urlError = error as? URLError else {return .failure(.unexpected(nil))}
                
            switch urlError.code {
            case .notConnectedToInternet,
                 .dataNotAllowed:
                return .failure(.addressUnreachable(urlComponents.url!))
            case .timedOut:
                return .failure(.unexpected("Request timed out. Try again"))
             default:
                return .failure(.unexpected(nil))
            }
           .failure(.addressUnreachable(urlComponents.url!))
        }
      }
```

The call site:

```
 let queryValue = "*,categories_details(*),accessories_details(*),colors_details(*),sizes_details(*),subcategories_details(*),price_ranges_details(*)"
        let queryItems = ["select": queryValue]
        let result = await sendRequest(endpoint: PCDBEndpoint.lookupTable(apikey: authManager.apikey, accessToken: authManager.apikey, queryItems: queryItems), responseModel: [LookupTable].self, keyDecodingStrategy: .convertFromSnakeCase)
```

Has anyone experienced this? How did you fix it? Is there an alternative way to debug this without Xcode 15? To avoid breaking changes introduced in iOS 17, is it possible to change a setting in Xcode that would make the code fallback to IOS 16.1 on iOS 17.

To resolve this issue, I attempted the following:
1- Symbolicate Crash Log
2- Run UI Tests to lunch the app using Xcode Cloud

1- Symbolicate Crash Log:
I have attached the symbolicated crashlog. Looking at that, it seems the issue has to do with the main function. I have also replaced the API call with static values.

[image: Crash Log]

[image: Crash Log ctd]

And Here is the main:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @StateObject private var appData = AppData()
    @State private var lookupTablesRequest: RequestStatus = .idle
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            VStack {
                if (lookupTablesRequest == .idle && !appData.lookupTables.isEmpty)  {
                    
                    MyAppView()
                        .onAppear {
                            AppReviewRequest.resetRequestRuns()
                            AppReviewRequest.resetPageViews()
                        }
                        .environmentObject(appData)
                } else if case .failed(let error) = lookupTablesRequest {
                    NoLoadedData(message: error.customMessage) {
                        Task {
                            await loadLookupTables()
                            
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        
                        if lookupTablesRequest == .loading {
                            ProgressView()
                                .controlSize(.regular)
                            Text("Getting The Static Collections Ready..".uppercased())
                                .accessibilityIdentifier("LoaderText")
                            // Text(statusText2)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            .task  {
                await loadLookupTables()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension PrettycharmApp {
    func loadLookupTables() async {
        
        lookupTablesRequest = .loading
        do {
            try await appData.loadLookupTables()
            lookupTablesRequest = .idle
        } catch {
            
            let requestError = error as! RequestError
            lookupTablesRequest = .failed(requestError)
        }
    }
    
}

// class AppData
class AppData: ObservableObject {
    
   @Published var lookupTables: [LookupTable] = []

   @MainActor
func loadLookupTables() async throws {
         
         let lookupTables = """
         [
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 1,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:40:38.246098+00:00",
                 "title": "categories",
                 "categories_details": [
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-06-19T15:51:12+00:00",
                         "category_title": "snack",
                         "category_id": "36515c22-c84f-4444-add4-c364ce56e162",
                         "lookup_table_id": 1
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-06-19T15:51:49+00:00",
                         "category_title": "cloth",
                         "category_id": "f3543cc7-b9c8-443a-b266-104f85580380",
                         "lookup_table_id": 1
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-06-19T15:52:19+00:00",
                         "category_title": "jewellery",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 1
                     }
                 ],
                 "accessories_details": [],
                 "colors_details": [],
                 "sizes_details": [],
                 "subcategories_details": [],
                 "price_ranges_details": []
             },
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 2,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:42:39.024016+00:00",
                 "title": "subcategories",
                 "categories_details": [],
                 "accessories_details": [],
                 "colors_details": [],
                 "sizes_details": [],
                 "subcategories_details": [
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "08bfd883-dc24-4310-9a46-6f0bd2bea5a2",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:26:29+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "1-piece set",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "89aa47c7-fcdb-4725-90d2-a8a91acff997",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:14:51+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "anklets",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "a7757d8f-61de-4241-b04e-d7f937da25f7",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:14:40+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "pendants",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "b6f4dad2-5dad-4dd4-8a45-e63022458dbd",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:15:18+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "bracelets",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "bf638ab8-1508-42c1-bcae-65efe99494ac",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:26:45+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "2-piece set",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "c465eff8-ecb7-4657-998d-a0977a4c5c9a",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:14:29+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "bangles",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "d5c987f4-0743-4160-8091-f243bf40f534",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:14:18+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "rings",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "d60197c8-7892-4918-b601-b4bfe02fd718",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:15:02+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "necklaces",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "d913f0de-e387-4540-b9af-c254e0d9a9db",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:23:12+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "3-piece set",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "fe19b1ab-2a67-42d5-93e6-b21adb93c972",
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:27:14+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "earrings",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     },
                     {
                         "subcategory_id": "8de270ee-3659-455b-abc8-650999189b86",
                         "created_at": "2023-02-07T11:16:50.106686+00:00",
                         "subcategory_title": "4-piece set",
                         "category_id": "ed348275-76e6-4967-b5d8-c625e1b8402d",
                         "lookup_table_id": 2
                     }
                 ],
                 "price_ranges_details": []
             },
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 3,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:43:16.1912+00:00",
                 "title": "accessories",
                 "categories_details": [],
                 "accessories_details": [
                     {
                         "accessory_id": "80b563f6-5388-4b7b-9686-fc68acc0ea98",
                         "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:53:17+00:00",
                         "accessory_title": "extensions",
                         "lookup_table_id": 3
                     },
                     {
                         "accessory_id": "2177c309-1a04-4055-8e4b-b5d5f0d1069a",
                         "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:53:37+00:00",
                         "accessory_title": "wiper",
                         "lookup_table_id": 3
                     },
                     {
                         "accessory_id": "fd424569-9c81-4764-b5aa-2ab3767db35d",
                         "created_at": "2022-06-10T18:53:47+00:00",
                         "accessory_title": "brush",
                         "lookup_table_id": 3
                     },
                     {
                         "accessory_id": "d296a7bc-a685-4c50-ada1-c076188aed7b",
                         "created_at": "2023-01-31T17:10:46.427525+00:00",
                         "accessory_title": "none",
                         "lookup_table_id": 3
                     }
                 ],
                 "colors_details": [],
                 "sizes_details": [],
                 "subcategories_details": [],
                 "price_ranges_details": []
             },
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 4,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:43:38.885198+00:00",
                 "title": "colors",
                 "categories_details": [],
                 "accessories_details": [],
                 "colors_details": [
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-06-19T12:51:57+00:00",
                         "color_title": "silver",
                         "color_id": "f579a3e6-758d-431a-89f3-9ebdabe43bfa",
                         "color_value": {
                             "b": 192,
                             "g": 192,
                             "r": 192
                         },
                         "lookup_table_id": 4
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:59:04+00:00",
                         "color_title": "white gold",
                         "color_id": "ac6ba2ee-ef7e-4c6e-b2d6-774d38f18e39",
                         "color_value": {
                             "b": 142,
                             "g": 165,
                             "r": 187
                         },
                         "lookup_table_id": 4
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:58:24+00:00",
                         "color_title": "gold",
                         "color_id": "7e97e6ab-29d8-4af3-a32d-858c615858b2",
                         "color_value": {
                             "b": 0,
                             "g": 215,
                             "r": 255
                         },
                         "lookup_table_id": 4
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:58:41+00:00",
                         "color_title": "rose gold",
                         "color_id": "bcb2b41e-4009-46b5-b4d9-38a78409152e",
                         "color_value": {
                             "b": 119,
                             "g": 108,
                             "r": 183
                         },
                         "lookup_table_id": 4
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T05:40:31+00:00",
                         "color_title": "mixed",
                         "color_id": "82f1b68d-9a23-4c86-8eeb-1f5756d4ffa9",
                         "color_value": {
                             "b": 225,
                             "g": 231,
                             "r": 226
                         },
                         "lookup_table_id": 4
                     }
                 ],
                 "sizes_details": [],
                 "subcategories_details": [],
                 "price_ranges_details": []
             },
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 5,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:44:13.027229+00:00",
                 "title": "sizes",
                 "categories_details": [],
                 "accessories_details": [],
                 "colors_details": [],
                 "sizes_details": [
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:44:58+00:00",
                         "size_title": "s",
                         "size_id": "bdec8999-6319-45e2-b8dc-2199e37531e1",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:45:43+00:00",
                         "size_title": "m",
                         "size_id": "1e8afcb4-5a25-4076-bc1d-16db98ef2e70",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:46:05+00:00",
                         "size_title": "l",
                         "size_id": "94c9af88-8830-40bb-adf8-8cbb005b2aa8",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:46:27+00:00",
                         "size_title": "xl",
                         "size_id": "417d1064-5027-4e2c-ad45-965f7e6bf3f4",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2022-04-29T04:46:37+00:00",
                         "size_title": "xs",
                         "size_id": "c48aafdf-7ad5-4fc6-accb-1d3de0f771e6",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     },
                     {
                         "created_at": "2023-01-31T17:11:47.711272+00:00",
                         "size_title": "one size fits all",
                         "size_id": "2da33760-0e00-4afd-9419-9f366bcc7018",
                         "lookup_table_id": 5
                     }
                 ],
                 "subcategories_details": [],
                 "price_ranges_details": []
             },
             {
                 "lookup_table_id": 6,
                 "created_at": "2023-02-09T10:44:30.403458+00:00",
                 "title": "price_ranges",
                 "categories_details": [],
                 "accessories_details": [],
                 "colors_details": [],
                 "sizes_details": [],
                 "subcategories_details": [],
                 "price_ranges_details": [
                     {
                         "id": 1,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:11:16.302103+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             0,
                             50
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 2,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:11:52.858243+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             50,
                             100
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 3,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:12:17.185552+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             100,
                             150
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 4,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:12:40.797355+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             150,
                             250
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 5,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:13:06.281451+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             250,
                             400
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 6,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:13:24.880879+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             400,
                             600
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     },
                     {
                         "id": 7,
                         "created_at": "2023-02-09T12:14:08.062709+00:00",
                         "range": [
                             600
                         ],
                         "lookup_table_id": 6
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
         """
         
         let jsonData =  Data(lookupTables.utf8)//try JSONEncoder().encode(lookupTables.utf8)
         let decoder = JSONDecoder()
         decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
         let lookupTablesList = try decoder.decode([LookupTable].self, from: jsonData)
         self.lookupTables = lookupTablesList
     }

}
```

2- Running UI Tests using Xcode Cloud:

On Xcode cloud with the os configuration set to iOS 17. I got this test failure which seems to confirm the runtime error I was getting on a real device running iOS 17.

Any help to fix this will go a long way.Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Can you get a symbolicated crash log from TestFlight to identify the details of the exception and the line?  Also, how are you building the app?  Are you building it on Xcode 14 with the iOS 16 SDK or are you using a CI platform so that it is being built on Xcode 15/iOS17 SDK?  If the former then you will soon need to do something about your Mac because Apple will require new submissions to use Xcode 17 SDK at some point in the new year.

Comment: @Paulw11 I will work on getting the symbolicated crash log from user. I built it with Xcode 14 with the iOS 16 SDK. I also used Xcode Cloud with iOS 17.0 to see if it could catch the bug. Thanks for the heads up about needing a Mac update. I will keep this post updated as I try to  resolve this issue.

Comment: Check in the testflight section in App Store Connect; crashes should be reported there.

Comment: @Paulw11 The Crash report in Appstore Connect don't provide any useful info. It's just info about the device on which the app crashed

Comment: If you mouse over the crash in App Store Connect it should say "Open in Xcode". Click on that to open the crash in Xcode. If that doesn't work then check in Xcode Windows->Organiser and then crashes

Answer (score 0):

You would want to start with parts of your code that can crash:

```
request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
```

This will crash if `body` contains non-plist values. (Plist-values are arrays, dictionaries, strings, numbers, booleans, and NSNull, and cannot include NaN or infinity. The top-level object must be an array or dictionary unless `.fragmentsAllowed` is passed.) This is one reason you should avoid JSONSerialization and prefer JSONEncoder. Your code seems to assume that it will throw an error, but it actually throws an exception, which Swift cannot catch.

This is where I would look first. I would look to PCDBEndpoint and ensure that in all cases, every property it returns is a plist-value. If you're including Apple types in this body, this is definitely a place I would look for your error, since the internal types may have changed, or a value may be NaN or infinity.

For details, see [`data(withJSONObject:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data):

> If `obj` can’t produce valid JSON, `JSONSerialization` throws an exception. This exception occurs prior to parsing and represents a programming error, not an internal error. Before calling this method, you should check whether the input can produce valid JSON by using `isValidJSONObject(_:)`.

See also [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization):

> To convert a Foundation object to JSON, the object must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary, unless you set the fragmentsAllowed option.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are neither NaN nor infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling `isValidJSONObject(_:)` or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if the JSONSerialization class can convert given object to JSON data.

```
return .success("" as! T)
```

This will crash in any case that T is not String (which it is not in this case). It is somewhat unlikely this is the cause, but crashing your app any time the server returns 204 unexpectedly is not a great idea.

```
return .failure(.addressUnreachable(urlComponents.url!))
```

This will never crash because earlier have checked that this with an `if-let`, but I would recommend using your local `url` here rather than `!`. You've done the `if-let` work already; you might as well benefit from it.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the refactor tips. If you take a look at the call site, the endpoint does not require a `body`. It's a `GET` request, so the `JSONSerialization` statement can't be the culprit.
As for PCBDEnpoint, it returns this an array of objects.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean here by "the endpoint does not require a `body`." Are you saying that you've verified that `endpoint.body` is always nil? Being a GET request in no way prevent `endpoint.body` from being serialized in your code if I'm reading it correctly. (HTTP doesn't even forbid having a body with GET.) Your callsite just calls `PCDBEndpoint.lookupTable()`, which you don't provide the code for.